# I need to find the Host URL, Site key and API key

Tags: api

I need to find the following details for my CiviCRM account:

- Host URL,
- Site key and
- API key.

Where can I find them?

Thanks so much,
Silvia

Answer (score 7):

### Host URL

Depending on the *context* of your situation, this is *probably* referring to the domain name of the site where you use CiviCRM. So if you see `https://example.org/civicrm` when using CiviCRM, then the host URL is `example.org`

### Site key

This is one value, used globally for your CiviCRM installation and stored in the `civicrm.settings.php` file on your server. (The location of this file will differ depending on what CMS you use.)

Within the file, you'll find a section like this:

```
if (!defined('CIVICRM_SITE_KEY')) {
  define( 'CIVICRM_SITE_KEY', 'J8UdnKcpN93x0mvv');
}
```

So here, your site key would be `J8UdnKcpN93x0mvv`.

### API key

API keys are unique to CiviCRM *contacts*. You'll need to [create an API key for a contact](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/interfaces/#keys) if you want to use the API through the REST interface.

If you are setting up an external service to connect to your CiviCRM installation, it's probably worth *creating a new contact record* specifically for this service to interact with your site. Then you can grant specific permissions to this user just like you would do for a real person.