# Where is the API key?

Tags: api

We want to connect CiviCRM with our payment processor (Twingle). We need to find the API key, the site key and the URL of the CiviCRM instance, but we can't seem to find them.

Where can we find them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I need to find the Host URL, Site key and API key](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20592/i-need-to-find-the-host-url-site-key-and-api-key)

Answer (score 8):

You can find the site key information you need in the System Administrator Guide: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/site-key/

The API key is in the database and needs to be set up for a contact that has access. You can install the API Key extension which will enable the API Key in the contact summary if you have admin rights: https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-key

The URL of the CiviCRM instance will be in your civicrm.settings.php. You can check it in the UI if you navigate to Administer>System Settings>Directories and click on the question mark in the green bit on the top of the screen. You will see a window in the right hand corner of the screen and the civicrm.root will be the URL for your CiviCRM instance.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you mean Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs?  civi.root can refer to root directory or root URL, depending on which context you're accessing it from.

Comment: I mean from Administer>System Settings>Directories and then click on the question mark. That will show you the directory AFAIK?

Comment: It will! But Marcos is asking for the URL, not the directory :)

Comment: My bad! So you should look in the Resource URL like @JonG suggested :-)